# Flutter fastlane ios how to pass --dart-define

Tags: ios, flutter, fastlane

I can't find answer for this.
My app needs parameters defined `--dart-define=ENVIRONMENT="$APP_ENV"`

There is no problem building Android, but how to pass those while build ad-hoc in fastlane?
I've prepared build scripts that run:

```sh
flutter pub get
flutter build ios --config-only \ 
    --flavor prod \ 
    --dart-define=ENVIRONMENT="$APP_ENV"

cd ios
bundle exec fastlane build_app_prod_ad_hoc
```

And my lane for fastlane is:

```rb
  lane :build_app_prod_ad_hoc do
    cocoapods
    gym(
      configuration: "AdHoc-prod",
      export_method: "ad-hoc",
      scheme: "prod",
      export_options: {
        provisioningProfiles: {
           ...
        },
      },
    )
  end
```

But I can see that my result doesn't have ENVIRONMENT set correctly.
Any ideas?

Comment: Did you manage to fix it?

Comment: I thought this would be a problem as well but with our CI script (`flutter build ios --release --no-codesign` and then fastlane beta which runs `build_app`), the dart defined values (in our case the backend URL) were correctly included in the app (verified because the app that landed in testflight is showing the correct data).

Comment: In the end I'm doing the same. 
First `flutter build ios --release ... with all defines`
And then run fastlane and build_app (gym) to prepare correct app, and then deliver this to developer center.

Comment: I'm having a hard with with this. I can see in the logs that when the lane build runs the flag is set, but then `build_app` from gym seems to create a new build without the `--dart-define` which results in environment being missed from the build.

Comment: @MiguelRuivo From what I understand, `flutter build ios --release --no-codesign --dart-define=VARIABLE=value` will create a file `Runner/Generated.xcconfig` (among others) which includes the dart defined values. That file is then incorporated into the gym build done by fastlane, so in your CI you are required to make sure that the flutter build runs in the same instance/folder/job as the fastlane build to make sure that this generated file is being used in the gym build.

Comment: Never mind, was just a bug in my code (environment variable was being set in lowercase whereas I was expecting it in upper on my code). Everything is working as it should using build + build_app from gym afterwards. Thank you.

Comment: But doesn't this significantly increase the CI time since we are now building the app twice? Did you find any alternatives?

Comment: Sadly It is compiling twice. But at least it works

Answer (score 5):

***Solution*:** 
Encoding and replacing your dart variable in **flutter_export_environment.sh** and **Generated.xcconfig** then running the app from Xcode/Fastlane directly will work fine.

------ Details -------

**The issue:** 
The variables passing via --dart-define won't reflect if you run the app from Xcode/ Fastlane directly without first running the flutter run/build command.

**Reason:** 
The following generated files are involved but not intended to update manually, but in our case running from Xcode or Fastlane to build the app, the dart variables used won't get updated. When you run the flutter run or build command, these files get updated with the values from --dart-define as Base64.

**/ios/Flutter/flutter_export_environment.sh 

ios/Flutter/Generated.xcconfig**

[image]

When you directly build the app from Xcode or use Fastlane, the Generated.xcconfig from the ios folder inside the Flutter project code is being used to run/build the app.

**Example:**
In my case, we pass the ENV variable using --dart-define, but if you run directly from XCode without running the flutter build or run command first, these arguments won't update.

flutter run/build --flavor dev --dart-define ENV=dev

Dart define variable will store in the flutter_export_environment.sh and Generated.xcconfig in Base64 encoding.

DART_DEFINES=RU5WX1UEU9chZ2luZw==

[image]

Note: *This is a workaround to avoid running the flutter run/build command followed by a Xcode/Fastlane run to solve the issue. Not the best solution, but I hope it may help someone.*

Answer (score 0):

I found a light solution without flavors using gitlab-ci.

1. Step 1: build your app without artifact:

```
flutter build ipa --build-number=$BUILD_NUMBER --dart-define="APP_ENV=$APP_ENV"
```

```
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - build/ios/ipa/app.ipa
    expire_in: 1 day
```

2. Step 2: create your lane for iOS publishing:

```
default_platform(:ios)

platform :ios do
  desc "Push a new beta build to TestFlight"
  lane :beta do
    api_key = app_store_connect_api_key(
      key_id: ENV['IOS_ID_KEY'],
      issuer_id: ENV['IOS_ISSUER_ID'],
      key_filepath: ENV['IOS_AUTH_KEY'],
      duration: 1200,
      in_house: false
    )

    get_certificates
    get_provisioning_profile
    upload_to_testflight(
      ipa: '../build/ios/ipa/app.ipa' # depends on the CI current directory,
    )
  end
end
```

Next step: build app with flavor to use different bundle identifier.

Hope it helps !