# Flutter xcode project ignores DART_DEFINES in CI pipeline

Tags: flutter, fastlane-gym

This happens in the following scenario:

I have two jobs (`build` and `deploy`) running in GitLab CI. In the build job I run `flutter build ios --release --no-codesign --dart-define=PROFILE="prod"` and in the deploy job I build the actual `IPA` for deployment via (`fastlane run gym scheme:"Runner" workspace:"Runner.xcworkspace" export_method:"app-store"`). The deploy job is based on and uses the entire `ios` sub project folder resulted from the build job.

Please note, since I have to set a specific provisioning profile in the pipeline which currently [isn't possible via the flutter tool](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/106612) I must use tools like `fastlane-update_code_signing_settings` & `fastlane-gym` instead of `flutter build ipa ...`

Unfortunately the built ipa doesn't respect `DART_DEFINES` which gets set in the build job even though I can confirm that [flutter_export_environment.sh and Generated.xcconfig exist and do contain `DART_DEFINES`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64396002/flutter-fastlane-ios-how-to-pass-dart-define/70982733#70982733) properly in the deploy job.

But when I also run `flutter build ios --release --no-codesign --dart-define=PROFILE="prod"` in the same deploy job (prior to the `fastlane run gym` command) then the built ipa does respect `DART_DEFINES` and the app works like a charm.

Thus, what am I missing here? I want to avoid having to run `flutter build ios` in the deploy job and keep the jobs separated. Do I have to run a specific script manually (which is eventually run by `flutter build ios` under the hood)?

Comment: Is it related to this perhaps? https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/136865

Comment: @Albert221 no, the issue there is about having env variables originating from DART_DEFINES (or alike) available during xcode/gradle build phase even though they must not be. Those variables are meant to be only available in the dart code